# how to replace value id jquery with array key, after spice than change value id to array key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have some problem work with the array, how to change **`id`** with a **new** key (new_index) of an array after splice?? splice in jquery success, but how to change value **"id"** in array ??..

```js
var each_arr = [{
    id: 0,
    judul: "JUDUL 1"
},
{
    id: 1,
    judul: "ICIK ICIK ehem"
},
{
    id: 2,
    judul: "ASOLOLE"
},
{
    id: 3,
    judul: "IWAK PEYEK"
}
];

$(".radio1").on('change', function(event, state) {
    var idarr = $(this).data("id");
    each_arr.move(idarr, 0);
    console.log(each_arr);
});

Array.prototype.move = function(old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= this.length) {
        var k = new_index - this.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) {
            this.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    return this;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radio1" data-id="0">0
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radio1" data-id="1">1
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radio1" data-id="2">2
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radio1" data-id="3">3
```

the script running but how to change value "id" with the array key after splice??

Comment: You want to re-order values of id key?

Comment: Unclear like this tells me it's time to sleep... My brain bleeds.

Comment: @Lalit i want change value id with new_index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, I had not changed your logic of sorting, just added a map function to update the `id` with the arr `key` like

`this.map((arr, i) => ({...arr, id:i}));`

```js
var each_arr = [{
    id: 0,
    judul: "JUDUL 1"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    judul: "ICIK ICIK ehem"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    judul: "ASOLOLE"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    judul: "IWAK PEYEK"
  }
];

$(".radio1").on('change', function(event, state) {
  var idarr = $(this).data("id");
  each_arr = each_arr.move(idarr, 0);
  console.log(each_arr);
});

Array.prototype.move = function(old_index, new_index) {
  if (new_index >= this.length) {
    var k = new_index - this.length;
    while ((k--) + 1) {
      this.push(undefined);
    }
  }
  this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  return this.map((arr, i) => ({...arr, id:i}));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radio1" data-id="0">0
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radio1" data-id="1">1
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radio1" data-id="2">2
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radio1" data-id="3">3
```

Comment: its work.. hey tanks very much.. i appriciated this help thank you..thank you..thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function instead of **`move()`**:

```
function move(array, value, positionChange) {
  var oldIndex = array.indexOf(value);
  if (oldIndex > -1){
    var newIndex = (oldIndex + positionChange);

    if (newIndex < 0){
      newIndex = 0
    }else if (newIndex >= array.length){
      newIndex = array.length
    }

    var arrayClone = array.slice();
    arrayClone.splice(oldIndex,1);
    arrayClone.splice(newIndex,0,value);

    return arrayClone
  }
  return array
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
//Use this function like as follow: this will not change the original array if you want to change original than assign the return value to the original array Where I use var temp_ar use each_arr instead for the change in original.

$(".radio1").on('change', function(event, state) {
  var idarr = $(this).data("id");
  var temp_ar = move(each_arr,idarr, 0);
  console.log(temp_ar);
});
```

Comment: how to use that function??